# Attaching pdf with sendGrid not working in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have write a mail sending functionality using sendGrid in c#. It works properly but when attaching the generated pdf as attachement, it's not working.

```
var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
var msg = new SendGridMessage()
{
    From = new EmailAddress(senderMailID, senderName),
    Subject = "ABCD",

};

var attach = new Attachment();
attach.Filename = "ABC.pdf";
attach.Content = "~/Templates/output.pdf";

msg.AddAttachment(attach);

msg.AddTo(new EmailAddress(receiverMailID,receiverName));
    var result = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);

}
```

Comment: You could improve this question by specifying what exactly is not working. E.g., include the exception that's thrown.

Comment: Your code is specifying the file path as the *content* of the attachment

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should be converting the file to a base64 representation (as seen in examples [here](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/commit/732c8ceaf14a55301c3572b2ccd3727398b94fa9)) of the file rather than adding a path to it.

A sample of the code needed:

```
var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
var msg = new SendGridMessage()
{
    From = new EmailAddress(senderMailID, senderName),
    Subject = "ABCD",

};
var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("~/Templates/output.pdf");
var file = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
msg.AddAttachment("ABC.pdf", file);
var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
```